# Are dreams just the world without the big Other?

Tags: psychoanalysis, lacan, dreams

Are dreams an alternative world where there is no big Other as the ever observing agency mentioned by Lacan?

Comment: No. Chances are tbey're an upshot of the brain attempting to clean itself up and fix any problems.

Comment: Interesting question, would you mind quoting Lacan here, for reference?